# Show that if a convex function $f$ is not everywhere differentiable then the Legendre transformation $f^{*}$ is not strictly convex.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

As per the title, I have come across this problem and I am completely stuck as to where to begin. Any pointers would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ is only subdifferentiable, but not differentiable at $x$.
Then there exist distinct $u$ and $w$ in $\partial f(x)$.
Denote the Fenchel conjugate of $f$ by $f^*$.
We also have $f^*(u)=\langle x,u\rangle -f (x)$ and
$f^*(w)=\langle x,w \rangle - f(x)$.
Let $v$ be on the line segment connecting $u$ and $w$ but different from both.
Then $v\in \partial f(x)$ and so $f^*(v)=\langle x,v\rangle - f(x)$.
Altogether $f^*(u)=f^*(v)=f^*(w)$ and $f^*$ is therefore not strictly convex.

Comment: @algevristis I am not sure I follow this comment - your question is about Legendre transform a.k.a. Fenchel conjugate.

Comment: Wrong post friend sorry will delete I was responding to another thing

Comment: I will check the solution when I get home and vote you up